# Windows XP Boot Conflict

Tags: boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

I have a partitioned drive with Windows XP on C and Ubuntu on D.  Following update of XP with last service pack I cannot get Ubuntu to boot.  Very frustrating.

Comment: Do  you still have Grub or other bootmanager installed?

Comment: While you didn't get in your situation by installing Windows, the question from Anwar's comment probably reflects the condition your system is in and the steps in the answers there are probably the best way to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to repair boot. There is a tool that make it very easy.

1. Boot from a Ubuntu [installed in a usb pendrive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key),
2. Install [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) by running these commands in terminal, one-by-one, and accepting prompts:

   1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`
   2. `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`
3. Run Boot Repair (press <kbd>Super</kbd>, type "boot-repair" and <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Comment: Thanks.  I don't have Ubuntu on USB or disk.  Installed by a friend in IT Dept.  I will need to obtain download.